# Why is my thread not ending when I interrupt it?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am making a skype like program.  I have an "accept" thread and multiple User threads for each call.  I store the accept thread in an arraylist every time a call is started.  What I need to do is when there is less than two people in the call is interrupt the accept thread that goes with the user thread that send the command.  To do this when an accept thread is created I log the index number and pass it on to all of the user threads so when it needs to send the interrupt command it just gets the thread from the arraylist using the index number.  But when I send it nothing happens. Could someone tell me why this is? Thank you in advance!!!

***Accept Thread***

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class accept extends Thread { // Chat and Voice Server User Accept
    private ServerSocket TextChat;
    private Socket sText;
    private int TextPort;
    private int index;
    boolean running = true;

    accept(int ChatPort) {
        TextPort = ChatPort;
        chat.threads.add(this);
        index = chat.threads.indexOf(Thread.currentThread());
        try {
            TextChat = new ServerSocket(ChatPort);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Cant create server on port "+ ChatPort);
            try {
                TextChat.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public void run() {
        while(running == true) {
            try {
                sText = TextChat.accept();
                System.out.println(sText+" Joined the chat");
                new TextChat(sText, TextPort, index).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Server on port "+TextChat+" Can't Accept");
                try {
                    TextChat.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Server on port "+TextChat+" Is Shutting Down");
        try {
            TextChat.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        running = run;
    }
}
```

***User Thread***

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TextChat extends Thread {
    private ObjectOutputStream out;
    private ObjectInputStream in;
    private Socket s;
    private String msg;
    private Boolean running = true;
    private int port;
    private String name;
private int threadIndex;

TextChat(Socket sText, int TextPort, int index) {
    s = sText;
    port = TextPort;
    threadIndex = index;
    try {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        if(port <= 65511) {
            chat.users1.add(out);
        }else {
            chat.users2.add(out);
        }
        in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void run() {
    while(running == true) {
        try {
            msg = in.readObject().toString();
            String[] part = msg.split("/");
                if(part[0].equals("MYNAME")) {
                    name = part[1];
                    System.out.println("NAME ADDED "+name);
                }
                if(!msg.equals(null)) {
                    if(port <= 65511) {
                        for(ObjectOutputStream o : chat.users1) {
                            o.writeObject(name+": "+msg);
                        }
                    }else {
                        for(ObjectOutputStream o : chat.users2) {
                            o.writeObject(name+": "+msg);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
                System.out.println(name+" Disconneted from chat");
                if(port <= 65511) {
                    chat.users1.remove(out);
                }else {
                    chat.users2.remove(out);
                }
                if(chat.users1.size() < 2) {
                    System.out.println("Chat server on port "+port+" is shutting down due to not enough people in call");
                    chat.threads.get(threadIndex).running = false;
                    running = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't get a decent answer soon, consider isolating the issue by creating a small program, the smallest one possible, that we can compile and run unchanged, and then test and modify and which shows us the problem, a [mcve].

Comment: I already did. my issue is that I cant access any of the objects in the accept thread and i cant interrupt it.  I was messing arround with it for a few hours.

Comment: No you didn't. Double check what you've posted as we can neither compile nor run it

Comment: You were told in your previous iteration of this question that what you needed to to was close the appropriate socket, not terminate the thread yourself. Don't repost questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you interrupt a thread, all it does is set a flag.  This flag is monitored by some operations, but unless you are using one of these operations, nothing happens.

If you have a thread which is blocked on IO, the most effective why to unblock the thread is to close() the stream or socket to kill it.  I would also set a flag e.g. `boolean closed` so you can detect that any IOException thrown was the cause of you closing the socket, rather than an error.

EDIT: Some suggestions.

- always uses `TitleCase` for class names.
- avoid mutable `static` fields wherever possible. In this case, I don't believe you need any.
- always pass shared state, and make sure it's thread safe is used from multiple threads.
- Don't extend `Thread` rather implement a `Runnable` and wrap it with a `Thread`
- You only need one server port in this cases, unless you are implementing this as a peer-to-peer service, but that doesn't appear to be the case.
- no need to write verbose expressions like `while (running == true)` when `while (running)` will do.
- if you have a `boolean running` which is shared between threads make sure it is volatile.
- DON'T catch an Exception and pretend it didn't happen. You are better off `throws IOException` on the constructor instead of creating a dead object.
- Wrap each client in an object, and only register this object, not the thread which runs the object. As you have noted, holding the Thread isn't very useful.
- Don't use a wrapper like `Boolean` when you don't expect a `null` value. Use a `boolean` which can't be `null` instead.
- I suggest using flags which are `false` by default. Instead of `running` used `closed`. This makes it easier to know what the default/normal value of the variable is.
- don't hard code ports like this in code, you should pass a flag or an id to say how it should behave.
- Only use Object Stream for passing general objects.  For passing text you can use a Writer/Reader or Data Stream which is simpler.
- You don't need to check for `null` for a value which cannot be `null` e.g. `msg.equals(null)` can''t every return `true`.
- Use the spell checker in your IDE `Disconneted` should be `Disconnected`
- I wouldn't disconnect when you have 1 as someone might be about to join.

Comment: I cant access any of the objects in the thread.

Comment: @mardis7021 You can access the Thread which is an object in that thread. Why can't you access any of the objects in it? Is this a requirement of homework, or it is a matter that you don't know how?

Comment: @mardis7021 BTW There is a lot about the structure of this code I would change.

Comment: This is a project i'm doing for myself.  I just don't know how.

Comment: I tried to make a running Boolean and make it static but i still cant access it.

Comment: `chat` appears to be a class rather than a variable. In that case it should be `Chat`. To solve you problem you need to make `Chat.threads` be a `List<Accept>`, none of the variable of `Accept` should be static.

Comment: @mardis7021 don't make a variable `static` if you expect it to be different for different instances. (In fact avoid mutable static variables where ever possible)

Comment: Ok I did that and it gave me this `Cannot instantiate the type List<accept>`

Comment: @mardis7021 `List` is an interface so you can't create it, you need to provide a thread safe instance like `List<Accept> accepts = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();`

Comment: Im getting this error now `
Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
        at java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.get(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:387)
        at java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.get(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:396)
        at TextChat.run(TextChat.java:62)
`

Comment: I updated the code.

Comment: @mardis7021 this means you are trying to access index `-1` which doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes I know but I searched for 1 and it still gave me the same error.

Comment: @mardis7021 That means there is not 2 elements in the list. You should be able to see that in your debugger.

Comment: I'm still getting that error and i checked to see if it is in the list and it is and when i get the index its -1.  but if i change it to 1 it gives me the error still. btw thank you for still helping me.

Comment: Now its making me do this `boolean running = true;` instead of this `private boolean running = true;` will that interfere if i have two accepts running.

Comment: @mardis7021 it should be private and it will only make a difference if you access it outside the class. Private doesn't change behaviour.

Comment: what do you think I should do about the previous question?

Comment: @mardis7021 you should use private fields where ever possible.

Comment: I'm still getting that error and i checked to see if it is in the list and it is and when i get the index its -1. but if i change it to 1 it gives me the error still. btw thank you for still helping me

Comment: @mardis7021 the first index is 0 not 1 so you need a size () of 1 to get (0). You need a size () of 2 to get (1)

Comment: First of all Thank you for all you're help.  And if its not to much for me to ask.  What is `CopyOnWriteArrayList` and why cant i just use an `ArrayList` instead of a `List` Thank you again.

Comment: @mardis7021 when you write/read a collection from multiple threads, you need a thread safe collection.  ArrayList is not thread safe but COWAL is.